# DataGrid view in asp.net is not displaying data

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

```
 I want to dispaly column in datagrid view using custom query statement
but i want to send value to parametrized data in query 
how can i do this ?
my code is below  

select 
c.customer_id,
c.customer_first_name,
c.customer_last_name,
c.customer_address,
c.account_number,
c.account_type,
a.account_balance,
t.transfer_amount_balance,
t.samebank_transfer_id,
t.account_number_same_bank,
 t.transferdatetime
FROM customer_details c join account_details a on c.account_number = a.account_number 
join transactions_details t on a.account_number = t.account_number where
c.customer_id = 'cus0010' and a.account_number = 'acc0010'

this above code working properly in sql server 2005
```

```
but the code below which is modified as per asp.net page for grid view is not showing
any result
select 
c.customer_id,
c.customer_first_name,
c.customer_last_name,
c.customer_address,
c.account_number,
c.account_type,
a.account_balance,
t.transfer_amount_balance,
t.samebank_transfer_id,
t.account_number_same_bank,
 t.transferdatetime
FROM customer_details c join account_details a on c.account_number = a.account_number 
join transactions_details t on a.account_number = t.account_number where
c.customer_id = 'Label1.Text' and a.account_number = 'Label2.Text'
```

```
 the above is placed in my custom sql query section it
 is triggered by button click in my asp page or any other
 idea to display it will be welcomed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use: 
`string.Format("c.customer_id = '{0}' and a.account_number = '{1}'", Label1.Text, Label2.Text);`

Consider this query:
`string query = "insert into TestTable (Column1, Column2) values (@p1, @p2)";`

p1 & p2 are parameters, in order to set the value for the parameters you need to use:

```
queryParameters[0] = new SqlCeParameter("p1", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
queryParameters[0].Value = Label1.Text;
queryParameters[1] = new SqlCeParameter("p2", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
queryParameters[1].Value = Label2.Text;
SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand(query);
command.Parameters.AddRange(queryParameters);
```

When the wizard is generating the query you need to use place holders/parameters for customer_ID and account_number and set their values by using parameters.

Edit:
In order to make the wizard create a parameter to use in the query, add a ? in the filter column in the query builder wizard.

Comment: it is not used in sqlquery string it used in wizard based custom sql

Answer (score 0):

Well, I may misunderstand, but...you are not actually sending the string 'Label1.Text' I guess? You should send the value of the textbox, something like this (if you are building the SQL as a string?):

...[SQL]... + "c.customer_id = '"+ Label1.Text + "'" ...[rest of the SQL]